# Counting visited nodes recursively

Tags: python, tree

I need to count the number of nodes I've visited on a tree whilst looking for a token (in this case a 1). So far I've come up with:

```
def search_recursive(node,rounds=0):
    if len(node)==2:
         if node[1]==1:
             print rounds
    else:
         rounds += 1
         huff_search_recursive(node[1],rounds)
         huff_search_recursive(node[2],rounds)
```

However, if I try to assign rounds to anything like:

```
def search_recursive(node,rounds=0):
    if len(node)==2:
        if node[1]==1:
            return rounds
    else:
        rounds += 1
        huff_search_recursive(node[1],rounds)
        huff_search_recursive(node[2],rounds)
```

Python assigns None, to any variable. For example.

```
rounds = search_recursive(node)
```

an example of a node is:

```
node = (1.0, (0.5, 0), (0.5, (0.25, 0), (0.25, (0.125, 1), (0.125, 0))))
```

Could anyone explain to me what's causing this bug, and how I could test for it in future?

Comment: Where do you return the value of intermediate steps?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17173822/python-issues-with-return-statement and quite a few others

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in each function call, `rounds` is a different variable.
changing it does not change the `rounds` variable of the outer function call.
you need to return the value and use the returned value.

```
def search_recursive(node):
    rounds = 0
    if len(node)==2:
        if node[1]==1:
            return rounds
    else:
        rounds += 1
        rounds += search_recursive(node[1])
        rounds += search_recursive(node[2])
    return rounds
```