# Whats wrong with this python return statement?

Tags: python, return

This code just find the largest number by divide and conquer algorithm. The code by itself works perfectly and finds the larges number and stores in my_data[0]. It prints the largest number correctly. But when I try to return it and store in 'val' variable, 'None' gets stored and not the largest number. Why the return statement is returning only 'none' instead my_data[0].. ?? I am not able to proceed the code since the return value is not correct. Can anyone say what fault is this ? Thanks in advance..

```
def largest(my_data):
    if len(my_data) == 1:
        print my_data[0]
        return my_data[0]
    else:
        alist = []
        blist = []
        for i in range(0,len(my_data),2):
            if my_data[i] > my_data[i+1]:
                alist.append(my_data[i])
                blist.append(my_data[i+1])
            else:
               alist.append(my_data[i+1])
               blist.append(my_data[i])
        my_data = list(alist)
        largest(my_data)
my_data = [12,45,63,13,76,87,23,85,56,123,7856,132,786,124,756,25366468]
val = largest(my_data)
print val
```

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17173822/python-issues-with-return-statement

Comment: This isn't really a divide and conquer algorithm. Divide and conquer splits a problem into multiple subproblems; for example, for this problem, divide and conquer would split the list in two, find the max of each half, and then return whichever sub-maximum is bigger.

Comment: Why are you going through all this, anyway? Even if you can't just use `max(my_data)`, it'd be simpler to just iterate through the list, keeping track of the biggest element you've seen so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write recursive code, you need to make sure that the value returned by the recursive call has to be propagated back. So,

```
    largest(my_data)
```

has to be returned like this

```
    return largest(my_data)
```

Also,

```
my_data = list(alist)
```

this statement is not necessary, if you are really trying to convert `alist` to a list. Because it already is a list. So, you can directly write

```
    return largest(alist)
```

Just curious, you are discarding the values added to `blist`, then why bother adding?

So, if you really don't need `blist`, then your code can be written with list comprehension, like this

```
return largest([my_data[i] if my_data[i] > my_data[i+1] else my_data[i+1]
                  for i in range(0,len(my_data),2)])
```

Comment: heyy.. thanks got it.. and now returning correctly.. Thanks a lot.. By the way this is just a staring code.. There are operations to be done on the blist also :) :)

Answer (score 0):

If you read your code, you'll notice that nothing is returned in the `else` clause. If you want this to be a recursive function, the usual thing is to return the value from the recursive call.